Orleans Cluster using docker container
Im using orleans and running silos in many vm each vm has the image of the server(silo) we develop
all silos joins the cluster but only the first one get the status 3 but all others get status 2 and then 6 when i read logs i figure out that silos are not able to communicate with each other Note(all vms are running on the same network)
this is the server configuration
 
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Orleans.Configuration;
using System.Net;
using Softylines.OrleansApp.Silo;

try
{
    StartSilo(args);
    return 0;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
    return 1;
}

static void StartSilo(string[ ] args)
{
  

    string sqlServerConnectionString = "Server=192.168.30.35;Database=OrleansDb;User Id=sa;Password=Anis2004#;";
 

    var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .UseOrleans((context, silo) =>
        {
            silo
                .UseAdoNetClustering(options =>
                {
                    options.Invariant = "System.Data.SqlClient";
                    options.ConnectionString = sqlServerConnectionString;
                })
                .Configure<ClusterOptions>(options =>
                {
                    options.ClusterId = "dev";
                    options.ServiceId = "aniss";
                })
                .Configure<EndpointOptions>(options =>
                {
                    options.AdvertisedIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.232");
                    
                    options.SiloPort = 11111;
                    options.GatewayPort = 30000;
                    options.SiloListeningEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 11111);
                    options.GatewayListeningEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 30000);
                })
                .ConfigureEndpoints("192.168.0.232", 11111,
                    30000, listenOnAnyHostAddress: true)
                .AddAdoNetGrainStorage(
                        name: "GrainStore",
                        configureOptions: options =>
                        {
                            options.ConnectionString = sqlServerConnectionString;
                        }) 
                .UseDashboard(options =>
                {
                    options.Username = "username";
                    options.Password = "password";
                    options.Host = "localhost";
                    options.Port = 9000;
                    options.HostSelf = true;
                    options.CounterUpdateIntervalMs = 1000;
                }) 
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {


                    logging
                        .AddConsole();
                }); 
        });

    var app = builder.Build();
    app.Run();
}

the docker file
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base  
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 443  
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build 
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Softylines.OrleansApp.Silo/Softylines.OrleansApp.Silo.csproj", "Softylines.OrleansApp.Silo/"]
COPY ["Softylines.OrleansApp.Grains/Softylines.OrleansApp.Grains.csproj", "Softylines.OrleansApp.Grains/"]
COPY ["Softylines.OrleansApp.Abstractions/Softylines.OrleansApp.Abstractions.csproj", "Softylines.OrleansApp.Abstractions/"]
 
 
RUN dotnet restore "Softylines.OrleansApp.Silo/Softylines.OrleansApp.Silo.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Softylines.OrleansApp.Silo"
RUN dotnet build "Softylines.OrleansApp.Silo.csproj" -c  Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish 
RUN dotnet publish "Softylines.OrleansApp.Silo.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish  

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Softylines.OrleansApp.Silo.dll"] 

and this is the compose i use each time in vms
services:
  softylines.orleansapp.silo1:
    image: kambo 
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Softylines.OrleansApp.Silo/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 11111:11111
      - 30000:30000

the silo register itself on the membership table with the host ip which is hardcoded in each vm

You should check logs on unhealthy instances, for now it's just a guess game.
